# FFmpeg RTSP authentication

Tags: authentication, ffmpeg, hash, rtsp

I've set up an encoding process from RTSP to HLS using FFmpeg, with success for most streams. However, for streams/cameras with digest authentication, FFmpeg fails with 401 Unauthorized:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i "rtsp://user:password@192.168.0.1/stream" /folder/output.m3u8
```

Giving:

```
ffmpeg version N-85750-ga75ef15 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
  libavcodec     57. 93.100 / 57. 93.100
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 88.100 /  6. 88.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'rtsp://username:password@192.168.0.1/stream'.
Reading option '/folder/output.m3u8' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url rtsp://username:password@192.168.0.1/stream2.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtsp://username:password@192.168.0.1/stream.
[tcp @ 00000000025c3900] No default whitelist set
[rtsp @ 00000000025c2560] method OPTIONS failed: 401 Unauthorized
[rtsp @ 00000000025c2560] CSeq: 2
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Use 'live' as User Name", nonce="2ae726f5557769220b780deb4f562226", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
rtsp://user:password@192.168.0.1/stream: Server returned 401 Unauthorized (authorization failed)
```

Camera is accessible and the input URI works in VLC, it is a Bosch.

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Answer (score 0):

your user or password need URI escape

```
string a = "rtsp://(.*):(.*)@(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3}):(\\d+)";
//string sName = "rtsp://admin:admin123@172.21.35.99:554/Streaming/Channels/102";
string sName = "rtsp://admin:admin123@172.21.35.99:554/Streaming/Channels/102";
regex reg_containport("(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3}):(\\d+)");
if (regex_search(sName, result, reg_containport))
{
    //包含ip和端口
    for (int i = 1; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
    }
    string a = result.prefix().str() + "aaaaaaaaaa" + result.suffix().str();
}
else
{
    regex reg0("(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3}).(\\d{1,3})");
    if (regex_search(sName, result, reg0))
    {
        //包含ip和端口
        for (int i = 1; i < result.size(); i++)
        {

        }
    }
}
std::cout << "Hello World!\n");
```